# How to run function only in one div Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have *ngFor with groups (its working), i need show "listofGroup" (in console works but in view no), in this specific group, my question is: how to run function in specific div in Angular2

**my html groups**

```
<div *ngFor="group in groups">
  <h4>{{group.name}}</h4>
  //here I want to call function where shows list in this group
  //I wrote this but not working
  <ul (load)="readListsGroup(group._id)">
    <li *ngFor="let listGroup of listsInGroup">
      <span>{{listGroup.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not do `*ngFor="let listGroup of readListsGroup(group._id)"`?

Comment: Show your readListsGroup function please

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you set property `listsInGroup` in `readListsGroup`.
It is not working, because you are calling `readListsGroup` in div for loop.
That means that `listsInGroup` have value of first group, and immediate after that it have value of second group and so on. After div for loop is ended, `listsInGroup` contains last value (value of last group) and this value is bind to all divs. Am I write?

You can rewrite template as user184994 write:

```
<div *ngFor="group in groups">
  <h4>{{group.name}}</h4>
  //here I want to call function where shows list in this group
  //I wrote this but not working
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let listGroup of readListsGroup(group)">
      <span>{{listGroup.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Code:

```
readListsGroup(group)
{
  const listsInGroup = findit();
  return listsInGroup;
}
```